# Remove dotted leaders only for a particular .tex file in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, leaders

I have .tex files for the first few section, for example, acknowledgement .tex file looks like this:

```
\doublespacing
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}\hspace{-.35in}\vspace{0.15in}{\SgIntTocSectionFormat{}Acknowledgements}}

\begin{acknowledgments}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum efficitur mi non pellentesque. Integer non nulla quis odio malesuada ornare nec et nunc.

\end{acknowledgments}
```

The declaration and acknowledgements have their own .tex file (via /begin{acknowledgements} and /end{acknowledgements}, and are also coded in the main .cls file as follows - this allows the usage of /begin and /end as mentioned earlier:

```
\newenvironment{acknowledgments}%
{%
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1.5cm}
        {%
            \Large \bfseries Acknowledgments
        }
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{quote}
}
{%
    \end{quote}
    
    \SgIntClearDoublePage
}
```

In the .cls file, I added dotted leader via this way:

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

which results in a table of contents as such (chapter has no dotted leaders, only sections/subsections, which is ok):

```
Declaration ................................... ii
Acknowledgements .............................. iii
1 Introduction
2 Literature Review                             1
  2.1 History of Something .................... 3
  2.2 Something else .......................... 5
3 Another Review                                7
  2.1 History of Nothing ...................... 9
  2.2 Nothing else ............................ 12
```

But I want to remove the dotted leaders for those specific .tex files such as Declaration and Acknowledgement (or rather, anything before Introduction)

```
Declaration                                     ii
Acknowledgements                                iii
1 Introduction
2 Literature Review                             1
  2.1 History of Something .................... 3
  2.2 Something else .......................... 5
3 Another Review                                7
  2.1 History of Nothing ...................... 9
  2.2 Nothing else ............................ 12
```

My entire final thesis.tex file to combine all these together is done via this way:

```
% The document.
\begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
        \SgAddTitle%
        \SgAddDeclaration%
        \input{acknowledgments}%
    \end{frontmatter}

    \input{chapter1}
        \input{chapter2}
        \input{chapter3}
        \input{chapter4}
        \input{chapter5}
        \input{chapter6}
    \SgIncludeBib{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Please let me know how I can achieve this? Ideally through adding something in the Declaration.tex/Acknowledgement.tex file to remove the dotted leader only for that particular entry.

I find no solutions online.

Comment: Welcome on TeX.SE. Please hep us to help you: make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete your code snipet iwith `\documentclass{...}`, the *required* `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Jhor, I have updated it. hope you/someone else may help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've given my suggestion as guess only, refer the below:

Add the below tag, before start of `Acknowledgements`

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\@dotsep{1000}}
```

and after complete the `Acknowledgements` part, please revert to:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\@dotsep{4}}%%how much you like
```

Comment: I have edited and updated the post. Could you kindly please check and update again? Please do let me know if you require any additional information from me. Your suggestion did not work (I assume you mean adding those before /begin{acknowledgement} and after /end{acknowledgement}

thanks

Comment: Please provide `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, it's much helpful to provide the better suggestion